# React changing body background using context and styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-context

The problem is that my background doesn't change, and I don't know why. I don't get any error messages. My button should change the background from light to dark. I think I have taken all the necessary steps for this one.

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  const toggleTheme = () => {
   theme === "light" ? setTheme("dark") : setTheme("light");
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme === "light" ? themeLight : themeDark}>
      <GlobalStyle />
        <button onClick={toggleTheme}></button>
        <Header />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Theme.js:

```
export const themeLight = {
  color: {
    background: "#fff",
  },
};

export const themeDark = {
  color: {
    background: "#000",
  },
};
```

GlobalStyle:

```
export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  .body {
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.background};
  }
`;
```

ThemeContext:

```
const ThemeContext = createContext(null);

export default ThemeContext;
```

I have two color objects in theme.js (themeDark and themeLight). I added styles (text and background) in the body. I created a ThemeContext file with createContext. I moved GlobalStyle from index.js (root) and ThemeProvider to App.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the dot before body in GlobalStyle and it should work.

```
export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.background};
  }
`;
```

Comment: Glad it worked.
If it's ok with you, then please mark the question as answered.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that there is an issue with your app. js.

```
 const toggleTheme = () => {
  theme === "light" ? setTheme("dark") : setTheme("light");
```

};

As you can see, when your theme is light, you have set it to dark, and in the themeProvider you have checked theme is triple equal to light, so you are using themeLight styling.

So, could you please check if you are checking in your toggleTheme function for the light theme, then set it to light only, not dark?

Please find below the change I am suggesting that might work for you and if doesn't work then try to console the theme which you are getting so that it can be easy for you to fix it.

```
 const toggleTheme = () => {
  theme === "light" ? setTheme("light") : setTheme("dark");
```

};